# `spring rspec` just displays spring help.. why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, spring-gem

I'm trying to use spring with rspec and guard on a Rails 3.2.16 project.

After installing spring and spring-commands-rspec, I created the binstubs with :

```
> bundle exec spring binstub --all
  * bin/rake: spring inserted
  * bin/rspec: spring inserted
  * bin/rails: spring inserted
```

Now trying to run spec with spring fails (gems paths and project path subtituted for legibility) :

```
> bin/rspec spec/
Version: 1.1.0

Usage: spring COMMAND [ARGS]

Commands for spring itself:

binstub         Generate spring based binstubs. Use --all to generate a binstub for all known commands.
help            Print available commands.
status          Show current status.
stop            Stop all spring processes for this project.

Commands for your application:

rails           Run a rails command. The following sub commands will use spring: console, runner, generate, destroy.
rake            Runs the rake command
rspec           Runs the rspec command
rspec binstub
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
gemspath/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load': cannot load such file -- [PROJECT_PATH]/rspec (LoadError)
from gemspath/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'
from gemspath/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'
from gemspath/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'
from gemspath/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
from gemspath/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:77:in `rescue in run'
from gemspath/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
from gemspath/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Other try :

```
> spring rspec
```

Only displays spring help

Same goes for

```
> spring rspec spec/
```

Here is the rspec binstub (bin/rspec) :

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
begin
  load File.expand_path("../spring", __FILE__)
rescue LoadError
end
require 'bundler/setup'
load Gem.bin_path('rspec', 'rspec')
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I have the exactly same problem. I hope somebody will answer!

Comment: `bundle exec spring stop` and then `bundle exec spring start` solved it for me.

Comment: @DarshanSawardekar it has not solved the problem for me and `spring start` is not existing. Which rspec Version have you running? i have 3.0.0-beta1. Probably its because of that.

Comment: Yeah, I'm on 2.14.7. Thanks for posting your answer, will come in handy when I get around to upgrading to 3.0.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## ANSWER OUTDATED! Was fixed. See @pfleidi's answer below.

I've solved the problem, even if i dont know why it has solved the problem.

Just remove `gem 'spring', group: :development` from the Gemfile so that you only have `gem 'spring-commands-rspec'` left.

Run `bundle install` and then `spring rpsec spec` will work! Its sooo fast :)

Comment: yes, the bug i had seems to be fixed in the new spring-commands-rspec version.

Comment: No, this solution is mere luck. This won't work if you don't restart spring.

Comment: At the time of the question, just stopping spring was not working. I tried that 20 times until i found this solution.

Answer (score 59):

I had the same problem. I've solved it by stopping spring and adding to my `Gemfile`:

```rb
gem 'spring-commands-rspec', group: :development, require: false
```

Spring needs to be restarted in order to use the newly added command.

```sh
bin/spring stop
bin/rspec path/to/file.rb
```

Comment: This is what fixed it for me

Answer (score 10):

You have to restart the spring. So stop it and then re-run it

`spring stop`

`spring rspec`

Then it should works as expected.